# Max(end_time) for max(date) value

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a table with 3 columns in hive database:

user
date
refresh_time

I would like to query the max(date) for user and max(refresh_time) for max(date) that I will get in the first step. I am able to do it in few steps (by creating extra table), however I would prefer to have one query. How to do it the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user order by date desc, refresh_time desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Wow! I have never tried window function! Works :) Thanks a lot for help!